# Cocoa-Touch string splitting

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In Cocoa-Touch, how can I split a string in more strings with only one character each? 
For example: I have an input string of four letters, I need to print in a different label each letter. How can I do it? 
Thx.

Comment: objective-c or what language? xcode can mean a lot

Comment: Obj-c... Or better, I'm building an iPhone app.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode, it's not possible -- Xcode is an IDE and not a programming language.

However, in Objective-C, you can access the characters or the 1-character substrings of an NSString instance and display them (you didn't clarify if it's OS X or iOS; I'll assume iOS since I'm more familiar with it):

```
NSString *s = @"abcd";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{
    UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aSuitableCGRect];
    l.text = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [aSuperview addSubview:l];
    [l release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks... An what if I want a second label with the second letter?

Comment: @user1552526 1. You see the for loop? 2. Can't you substitute one number to another using logic? I guess we're not in kindergarden anymore...